# lights in kitchen have no power

Tags: electrical

my kitchen has 3 lights that are not working. One dining table light a over the sink light and the main kitchen light which were 6 T12 lights replaced with 6 LEDs (t8's)that required no rewiring.  all the wall receptacles have power and are working. Here is what I did so far:
-checked the gfci outlets and none of them were tripped but I pushed reset anyways.
-went outside to my breaker box and none of those were tripped but I also reset them all anyways. 
-took all the switch covers off the light switches and tested that they all have no power.
-checked the wire nuts behind the light switch and they're all very secure.
-took the breaker panel off and tested each breaker. all had 123V.

What should I do next?
Im thinking replace all the light switches?

or check all the wall receptacles... I assume all kitchen lights and wall outlets are separate.

any other options out there, please help. 
i havnt checked the light bulbs themselves because like all the lights are LED...I slowly upgraded them over a period of like a year. with the last ones being about 4 months ago.

location: Sacramento, California

Comment: When you say "required no rewiring" did you remove the fluorescent ballasts/starter/etc? T8 LED tubes vary enormously in how they need to be wired up and how the pins at each end are used.

Comment: Since the problem started with changing the lamps in the last fixture I would double check that fixture wiring. if the other lights are daisy chained and replacing the lamps loosened a connection in this fixture this could be the cause. Replacing all the switches is just throwing parts at it. Verify the voltage at the fixture and that all wire nuts are secure.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick He means he used the type that do not require re-wiring the ballast, *but need a ballast*.

Comment: The lights are not the problem. I replaced them months ago. I was just describing what lights were on the system. All three outlets. Don't have power. All wirenuts are secured. How doI proceed

Answer (score 2):

All the light switches should have power at all times on one screw.  The other screw ahould have power when switched on.   According to your description, they don't.

That means whatever is feeding the light switches is not doing so.  If you have receptacles which are also broken, keep following the chain toward source.  You may be a broken GFCI or the GFCI itself may not be getting power.

It may be a problem with the neutral.

It is almost assuredly one single problem.   Double failures are very unusual.

If necessary, undo wire nuts and measure voltage on each wire.